# Curve equation from curvature

Tags: curvature

I'm trying to get a curve equation from curve curvature (trying to design a bent air pipe with later boundary layer separation). I should also mention that my math is pretty rusty.

My idea was to have a bend curve that would have a linear decreasing curvature k(s).
I checks stackexchange for similar questions (linked bellow) and from my understanding, I would have to define a k(s) function and then integrate it twice.

s - arclength

c(s) - curve equation

k(s) - curvature equation

n(s) - unit normal vector

c''(s) = k(s) * n(s)

How can I get the normal unit vector as a function of arclength s?

Related topics:

[Given the curvature, find the equation of any curve in plane](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2055346/given-the-curvature-find-the-equation-of-any-curve-in-plane)

[Curve from curvature](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1136859/curve-from-curvature)

Comment: For a curve in the plane you don't need that normal unit vector $n(s)$. The succint answer (copied over here) is: $$\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} x_0+\int_0^s \cos \left( \int_0^s \kappa(s) \, ds \right) \, ds \\ y_0+\int_0^s \sin \left( \int_0^s \kappa(s) \, ds \right) \, ds \end{pmatrix}$$ For a curve in $\mathbb R^3$ that $n(s)$ is an extra degree of freedom. In other words, you don't get it, you put it. Take a circle and a helix. They both have the same curvature but different motion of $n(s)$.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. Do you perhaps know how the answer above is derived ? I'm trying to understand.

Comment: Take derivatives to verify $\ddot c=\kappa\cdot n$.